# how to check property type in t4 template

Tags: t4

i want to check property type in t4.i want to get the property and check in t4. 
Please give a solution

```
 foreach (PropertyMetadata property in ModelMetadata.Properties)

  {

   //here how to check
  if(proprty.Type.ToString=="string")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
property.UnderlyingType == typeof(string)
```

Good Luck

Comment: Why you edited my answer? what is the difference between my answer and your edited answer? and why you down voted my answer? Did you try it before??? By the way I am new in stackoverflow.

Comment: i am not sure but i got it in a different way. i used property.TypeName==typeof(string)

Comment: sorry i am bit new to stackoverflow